# left join gives more results

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have this query:

```
SELECT wc.city, wc.country_id, wc.latitude, wc.longitude FROM 
world_cities wc
-- left join states s on wc.country_id = s.country_id
where wc.city = 'rosemount'
```

With that I get 6 results (what I want), if I un-comment the the 3rd line, I get 150ish results. How come when I un-comment the 3rd line I get more results, shouldn't I still only get 6? I feel like I am missing something here...

**States**

```
mysql> describe states;
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| state_id   | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| country_id | tinyint(3) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| state_name | char(15)            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**World Cities**

```
mysql> describe world_cities;
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| city_id     | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| state_id    | int(11)             | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| country_id  | tinyint(3) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| country     | char(2)             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| city        | char(60)            | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| accent_city | char(60)            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| region      | int(11)             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| population  | int(11)             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| latitude    | decimal(9,6)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| longitude   | decimal(9,6)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**Edit**
I have now run this, it updates state_id in the world_cities table fairly well.

```
update world_cities wc 
left join zipcodes z on wc.city = z.city 
left join cities c on z.state = c.city_name
left join states s on z.state = s.state_name 
set wc.state_id = s.state_id 
where wc.country_id = 236
and abs(round(z.lat, 2) - round(wc.latitude, 2)) between 0 and 1
and abs(round(z.log, 2) - round(wc.longitude, 2)) between 0 and 1;
```

Comment: Still get the same results

Comment: Are you sure you want to join to the `states` table on `country_id`? Shouldn't it be `state_id`?

Comment: world_cities doesn't have a state_id, it has all the cities in the world in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 6 records in `world_cities` with a city of "rosemount", but you have *many* states that belong to the same country as each of these cities. For instance, Detroit MI, USA is the same country as all other states in the USA. So I would expect something like 300 = 6 * 50 in my example.

Most likely you wanted to join with another condition: `wc.country_id = s.country_id AND wc.state_id = s.state_id`. Looking at your schema, there is no possible way to identify to which state a city belongs. You'll need to create a world_cities.state_id column.

Comment: It has one now, but I have no way of populating it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are joining on the wrong field.  Try this:

```
SELECT wc.city, wc.country_id, wc.latitude, wc.longitude FROM 
world_cities wc
-- left join states s on wc.state_id = s.state_id
where wc.city = 'rosemount'
```

If a city is in the US, then you might have 50 (or 57) states that match the country id.